# Unity : I can't change the opacity of an image or change its color in RGB

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I want to change the color of a square at runtime which is simply a game object with an `Image` component.
In my script I proceed like this:

```cs
private Image imageRenderer;


imageRenderer = ImageCompleteSquat.GetComponent<Image>();
imageRenderer.color = Color.red;
```

In this case, it works and the image turns red as expected. But as soon as I change this line by putting my own RGB color like this:

```cs
imageRenderer.color = new Color(227, 66, 52);
```

The image is not displayed anymore: it disappears.
Does anyone know how to change the color of an `Image` component?

Comment: It may be possible you're trying to make a color that doesn't exist. Unity's ```Color(r,g,b)``` constructor takes float values between 0 and 1. not 0 and 255. putting a number greater than 1 might just make it an invisible value [Example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html)

Comment: [Here's](https://answers.unity.com/questions/610337/color-components-higher-than-1.html) an example listed on Unity's forums. does this help?

Comment: Make sure your material is transparent or fade. and image be a PNG

Comment: @RageMan thanks, that was it, I feel a bit stupid but the problem is solved

Comment: @Simon Don't worry about it! Most GUIs today use rgba as float/double values between 0-1 but some, like JavaFX, use 0-255 so it's a little confusing and frustrating not knowing if the language uses 0-1 or 0-255. It's a pretty common mistake!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to set the alpha value first

```cs
imageRenderer = ImageCompleteSquat.GetComponent<Image>();
var tempColor = Color.red;
tempColor.a = 1f; // change this value (floating point between 0 and 1)
imageRenderer.color = tempColor;
```

Comment: It could have been that but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs of `Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html), each color component is a floating point value with a range from `0` to `1`. Hence just divide the arguments passed into `Color()` by 255

```cs
imageRenderer.color = new Color(227/255f, 66/255f, 52/255f);
```